# Error database is locked sqlite vb.net

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlite, database-connection

hi I'm trying to insert a row to my database but I still get this error message (see below):

[image]

I used the methode using to be sure that the connection will be closed.
below the script for the insert button :

```
 Private Sub MTB_Insert_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MTB_Insert.Click
        cmd = New SQLite.SQLiteCommand
        Using con As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(constr)
            Try
                'con.ConnectionString = constr
                con.Open()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Material_Type (Material_Type,Material_Type_Description) values(@Type,@Description)"
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", MTTB_Material_Type.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", MTTB_Material_Description.Text)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MessageBox.Show("Successful Added Data")
                'Calling function load data
                loadDatadg1()
                'con.Dispose()
                'con.Close()
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Sub
```

other parts of my code :

```
Public Class F_Update
    Dim con As SQLite.SQLiteConnection
    Dim cmd As SQLite.SQLiteCommand
    Dim da As SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter
    Dim constr As String = "Data source =Database1.db"

    Public Sub loadDatadg1()
        Using con As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(constr)

            'con = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(constr)
            con.Open()
            Dim str As String = "select * from Material_type"
            da = New SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter(str, con)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds, "Tb.Material_Type")
            dg1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Tb.Material_Type")
            'da.Dispose()
            'con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub

    Private Sub F_Update_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Using con As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(constr)
            ' con = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(constr)
            con.Open()
            'MsgBox("OK")
            'Calling the function Load form
            loadDatadg1()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

another part :

```
Private Sub B_login_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_login.Click
        Dim connectionString As String = "Data source =Database1.db"
        Dim mSQL As String = "select User_Name,User_Password from User where (User_ID = 1 and User_Name = '" & T_User_Name.Text & "' and User_Password = '" & T_User_Password.Text & "')"
        Dim dt As DataTable = Nothing
        Dim ds As DataSet
        Dim rd As SQLiteDataReader
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)

            Try
                con.Open()
                Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(mSQL, con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                rd = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
            End Try

            If rd.HasRows Then
                F_Update.Show()
                Me.Close()
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid User Name or Password")
            End If
            'con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

can some one help me please ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks jamiedanq for you answer, but how to do it ? I don't use a server it's an embbeded database

Comment: restart your computer

Comment: I did it without any success

Comment: try `cmd.Dispose()` after `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

Comment: Use Breakpoint and trace the code line by line to check the error line no. That'll help tracing error.